# How to replace exsisting SQL queries with Hibernate in exsisting jsf application?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have multiple dao classes, I want to replace them with Hibernate ORM. I have generated all the POJOs and mapping for each table. Now, I don't know how to move ahead. Can someone help ?   Thanks in advance.

Comment: Help with what exactly? Now you have to go learn the Hibernate API and query language and get to work replacing all the SQL logic.

Comment: I have multiple java files with SQL queries(DAO files). Now, I am designing a hibernate ORM for my application. I have cfg.xml and all hbm.xml ready, also I have created POJOs for all the tables in DB. Now, I'm trying to implement Hibernate by replacing or modifying these DAOs with java objects. I wants to know how should I write my HQL queries? 

Sorry for lack of clarity, this is my first question here.

Comment: Nothing changes: you need to learn HQL. Nobody can help you with that, buy a good book or use the rich Hibernate documentation and get to it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to replace the SQL queries, just setup the hibernate configuration & use the createSQLQuery method

```
String sql = "SELECT * FROM EMPLOYEE";
SQLQuery query = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
```